# Colorbox width doesn't count vertical scrollbar

Tags: colorbox, css

Hy,

I know a fix exist but i didn't bookmark the page :/

I use colorbox to load an iframe containing an image. If the iframe is higher that the window height, there is a vertical scrollbar, logic !
But the width doesn't count the width of the scrollbar and put an horizontal scrollbar too and that suxx ! I just want to add 20px more on the width if the height of the image is higher than the "maxHeight" value.

Here is the basic code i use :

```
$("a.colorbox").colorbox({ maxWidth:'90%', maxHeight:'90%', scalePhotos: true, photo:true });
```

[And this is what's happen !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYf1b.jpg)

Thanks,

Comment: #cboxLoadedContent{overflow-x:hidden !important;} works but iframe is still cropped under the vertical scrollbar !
I need something like : 

width += (maxHeight < innerHeight) ? 20 : 0;

Answer (score 2):

A fix is available here :
[jeremysawesome  patch](https://github.com/jeremysawesome/colorbox/commit/4a74c20a3f922648093fc6de69004291d87dec17)

However, it needs a small change for the last version of colorbox (1.5.5) :

Replace line 640 : `if(settings.scrolling){`

By this one : `if(settings.get('scrolling')){`

Comment: This is the correct solution ! 7 month after :)
Thanks you !